# How to save copied font in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, fonts, save

I'm trying escape string using `db.escape` but it's through error. I'm using MySQL Node.js as back-end. Is there any way to save data into database?

```
"INSERT INTO address SET  address = '        .'";
```

> Formatted text in address below.
>
> "INSERT INTO address SET  address = '        .'";
>
> This query return MySQL `error`.

Comment: This is not a font, this is a different Unicode codepoint/character that renders differently. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The same thing I want to know that if customer copies his address from somewhere and paste in to the input. Then MySQL show error. That's why I don't put my code in code the snippiest @MarkRotteveel

Comment: I just want to convert formatted text to plain text using NodeJS or MySQL @MarkRotteveel

Comment: That is not what you're asking though, and you never mention any error. That is why you need to be specific about the problem you're trying to solve, provide any relevant errors, expected results, actual results and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. In short, a [mre].